# Consolidate and show all the occurrences based on date and country

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have a dataframe like that

```
Date        | Country | Occurrences
2021-08-25  |   CA    |     188
2021-08-25  |   AE    |     10
2021-08-25  |   BE    |     25
2021-08-25  |   GR    |     49
2021-08-26  |   CA    |     200
2021-08-26  |   AE    |     7
2021-08-26  |   BE    |     27
2021-08-25  |   GR    |     52
```

and I want to show it like this

```
Date        | CA  | AE | BE | GR
2021-08-25  | 188 | 10 | 25 | 49
2021-08-25  | 200 | 7  | 27 | 52
```

How do I go about doing it? I tried `df.explode('Country')` but it did not take into consideration the occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `df.pivot_table()`.

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-08-25', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-26', '2021-08-26', '2021-08-26', '2021-08-25'],
        'Country': ['CA', 'AE', 'BE', 'GR', 'CA', 'AE', 'BE', 'GR'],
        'Occurrences': [188, 10, 25, 49, 200, 7, 27, 52]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Country', values='Occurrences')
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know of the pivot_table function